# Creating cookies when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, session-cookies

I need to know how to create a cookie on submit from a form.

I have a page that shows a window from colorbox when you visit it. Inside the pop up is a form for a newsletter email signup. If the user clicks off the form or cancels the cookies should only expire for 1 day. If the user submits their email on the form the cookie should expire for 1 year. So basically i need the form to overwrite the cookie if submitted. and here is what i have so far for code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../cb/colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../cb/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function showModal() {
  $.colorbox({href:"content.php", open: true,iframe: true,width:"400px", height:"200px"});
}

var visited = readCookie('mypopup');

if (!visited) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    showModal();
    createCookie('mypopup','no',0);
  });
}

//]]>
</script>
```

So need the onSubmit cookie code so i can place that on my "content.php" page so it overwrites this existing cookie when submitted.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with your existing code?

Comment: @matmarbon it does not set a cookie when someone submits a form